# Swift: lazy instantiation of IBOutlet var UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to do an lazy instantiation of  IBOutlet var UITableView:

```
 @IBOutlet lazy weak var tableView: UITableView? = {
        return UITableView()
    }()
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'UITableView?' to return type 'UITableView?'
<unknown>:0: error: cannot assign value of type 'UITableView?' to type 'UITableView??'
<unknown>:0: error: cannot assign value of type 'UITableView?' to type 'UITableView??'
```

Why I'm getting this error?

In this other case works just fine:

```
lazy var viewController: ViewController = {
        return ViewController()
    }()
```

Comment: I don't think you need to lazily instantiate a `UITableView`. Would just leave it as a vanilla outlet and get on down the road.

Comment: If it's an outlet, why would you be creating an instance in code?

Comment: @Adrian, can you post an example?

Comment: @rmaddy, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Outlets are used to reference a view you create in your storyboard, not via code.

Comment: Just drag a connection from Interface Builder to your ViewController and name it `tableView`. Make sure you set `tableView.dataSource = self` and `tableView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate the outlet explicitly, it's storyboard's job to do that when your View Controller is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right way to connect your ui elements to the Interface builder, take a look, it should help:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible, and kind of senseless.

When you mark a property as an `@IBOutlet` and connect your code to your `.storyboard` or `.xib`, it will look like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    ...
}
```

Notice, that `tableView` property does not have an initialiser. This is because it will not be initialised during `MyViewController` construction, but will be assigned later when interface builder will load the view. Also, this will only happen if you instantiate your view controller via storyboard or xib. Doing `let viewController = MyViewController()` will result in `tableView` property always being nil (unless you override your constructors or `func loadView()`).

`lazy` properties on the other hand MUST have an initialiser, which will be called lazily after you first access the property. Just like you've done in your code. The thing is, when you mark your `tableView` as `lazy` and provide your own initialiser for it, in runtime it will create an `UITableView` instance, which is not connected to your interface builder (`.storyboard`) in any way.

So you should either not use storyboards and make your layout programmatically (just like you did in your code, but removing @IBOutlet), or let the interface builder instantiate your views for you by removing your initialiser and `lazy` keyword.